# Nome da medalha "Revisor" está em inglês na notificação

Tags: bug, status-pronto, tradução, medalhas

Ao receber a medalha de **Revisor**, notei que na notificação o nome dela ainda está a ser apresentado em Inglês onde se pode ler **Proofreader**.

[image: Realizações Recentes]

Contúdo, ao consultar a lista de medalhas a mesma está com o nome em Português de **Revisor**.

[image: Separador Medalhas]

Comment: Posso confirmar que a situação está igual à data de hoje.

Comment: @Zuul eu tinha redigido daquele jeito pois tenho a impressão que acontece com qualquer medalha, mas não tenho certeza. Se confirmarmos isso mais adiante, editamos outra vez.

Comment: Sim, posso confirmar que acontece com outras medalhas, mas assim fica isolado para esta medalha em particular pois não sei se a resolução do problema é comum a todas as medalhas. :/

Answer (score 2):

Isto foi resolvido, mas as mensagens ainda aparecerão em inglês enquanto não estiverem traduzidas.

---

This has been fixed, but the messages will appear in English until they are localized.